# Angular при сборки проекта показывает ошибку

Tags: webpack

В консоле браузера:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
polyfills.bundle.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
    at polyfills.bundle.js:1`
`styles.bundle.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
    at styles.bundle.js:1`
`vendor.bundle.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
    at vendor.bundle.js:1`
`main.bundle.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
    at main.bundle.js:1
```

Comment: Друзья помогите кто сможет!!!

Comment: Друзья нашел ошибку, оказывается проблема в браузере очистил кеш и все сработала,